# How to add body background color or border to track it in box2d?

Tags: box2d-iphone

im using box2d physic engine, is there any way to track bodies where it collides or from where it is applied forces like wise?

Answer (score 0):

There is a functionality for box2d called Debug-Draw you could use that.

Debug Draw in Box2D is a special feature that draws all the bodies in the physics world on the screen for debugging purposes.  It is helpful because sometimes you can't tell if your image is in the wrong location or your physics body is in the wrong location.